# Grails get field value by id in groovy clause

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm trying to set autofill in a form in that whenever the id field changes in the form, several other fields would autofill. I am using jQuery for the on change event.

This is the id field:

```
<g:field id="id" name="id" value="${this.myContoller?.id}"/>
```

And this is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id").change(function(){
            $("#otherField").change("${info.getOtherField('#id')}")
        });
     });
```

Info is a taglib that I am using to pull the info I need for that field. I cannot figure out how to pull the data from the field into the groovy code inside of the jquery statement.
I am using Grails 3.

Comment: You can't. You can't access client side data with the server side processing which has already been done. So in your case #id will never evaluate.

Comment: So what would be a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Make an AJAX call to a controller to fetch the data, you could even use the tag library from within your controller if you have to.

Comment: ${info.getOtherField('#id')} is this value going to change after the form is rendered ? If not then  $("#otherField").val("${info.getOtherField('#id')}") will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Joshua Moore said you can't callout to the server side without as ajax call. Here's one way of doing that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'getTheOtherFieldValue')}",
        data: {
          'id' : $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
          $("#otherField").change(data.theOtherFieldValue)    
        }
    });


  });
});
```

And your controller can look like,

```
MyController {
...
  def getTheOtherFieldValue(String id ) {
    render(contentType: 'text/json') {
      theOtherFieldValue = getOtherField(id)
    }
  }
...
}
```

Basically, your trigger makes an ajax call to the server with the #id values, waits till it returns and then updates #otherField with the returned value(s)

Comment: This almost works. I'm getting an error in the controller saying:
`No such property: theOtherFieldValue for class: groovy.json.StreamingJsonBuilder$StreamingJsonDelegate.`

Comment: I found the issue. In the controller, the rendered value should be set up as: `val{val{theOtherFieldValue:getOtherField(id)}}` and in the jQuery the code that sets the value should be `$("#otherField").val(data.val.val.theOtherFieldValue)`